# Find Min-Max values of array without using Linq?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, max, min

I've been working on this assignment for my programming class for a little bit and though I had it solved. A little info for anyone interested: My task is to find the score of the competitor from an array of scores (eg, int[] scores = 4, 5, 6 , 7, 8, 9). BUT I must not include the highest and lowest values when adding the rest of the scores together (eg, score would = 5+6+7+8 (no including 4 and 9)).

My solution when we were allowed to use linq was as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Scoring {
class Program {


    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] scores = { 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6 };

        remove_duplicates(scores);
        console_text(scores);


        ExitProgram();
    }


    static void remove_duplicates(int[] scores) { //removes duplicat values from array

        var pScores = scores.Distinct().ToArray();

    }



    static int result(int[] pScores) { //calculates results by removing max and min scores, then adding the remaining.

        return pScores.Sum() - pScores.Max() - pScores.Min();

    }


    static void console_text(int[] pScores) { //renders the text in the consol window

        int final_score = result(pScores);


        Console.Write("Competitor your scores were " );
        foreach (int i in pScores) {
            Console.Write(" " + i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n" + "           and your score was " + final_score);

    }





    static void ExitProgram() {
        Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to exit program: ");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }//end ExitProgram

}
}
```

So I thought I was done, but now I have recieved and email stating:

"cannot use any system.array methods nor can you use any functionality of Linq or any other library class you may discover"

This has me a bit lost and confused, any help at all would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: And also no duplicate values?

Comment: One way is to loop through the array with a temp variable, comparing the next value with the current one - if it's less than the current one, it's the new min (or if it's greater than the current one, it's the new max).  At the end of the loop you'll have the min (or max) value.

Comment: it seems you have to do it the old way. try Tims suggestion. use a for statement to get the min and max value within the arrray. then sum them up excluding the min and max. or you can sort them first then sum up from index 1 to score.length - 2 after sorting. your choice.

Comment: It's a little more involved than what I described.  I suggest googling for algorithms on finding min/max/distinct values in a collection (or array).

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, just wondering though, isn't the sort method from system* though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option. The only thing that is not very clear is weather if there are two equal values which are also min values or max values they should be removed both or only one max value and one min. I remove just one min and one max value:

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6 };

        int Lowest = arr[0];
        int Highest = arr[0];
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Lowest > arr[i])
            {
                Lowest = arr[i];
            }
            if (Highest < arr[i])
            {
                Highest = arr[i];
            }
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        sum -= (Lowest + Highest);
        Console.WriteLine("The sum withot the highest and lowest score is : {0}", sum);
```

and if you and to remove all duplicated min and max scores add this before summing the final score:

```
int[] arrOfHighest = new int[arr.Length];
        int[] arrOfLowest = new int[arr.Length];
        int minCounter = 0;
        int maxCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Lowest == arr[i])
            {
                arrOfLowest[minCounter] = arr[i];
                minCounter++;
            }
            if (Highest == arr[i])
            {
                arrOfHighest[maxCounter] = arr[i];
                maxCounter++;
            }
        }
        int sumLoewst = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrOfLowest.Length; i++)
        {
            sumLoewst += arrOfLowest[i];
        }
        int sumHighest = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrOfHighest.Length; i++)
        {
            sumHighest += arrOfHighest[i];
        }
        sum -= (sumLoewst + sumHighest);
```

So the final touch based on the additional information. Since you want the min and max value to be added only once each inthe code above - `sum -= (sumLoewst + sumHighest);` right after this add:

```
sum -= (sumLoewst + sumHighest); 
sum += (Highest + Lowest);
```

This way you will have all other values summed, no matter how times they appear in the array. And only one `MAX` and one `MIN` value added to the sum.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Really appreciate it! Just wanted to get some thing clarified if that isn't too much trouble. As I'm new to programming and c#, could you explain this line please: "int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++", I cant really get a proper grasp on it. Thanks agian

Comment: Here's a reference for the for loop on MSDN: [for C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx)

Comment: It's very basic programming construction called `Loop`. In order to be able to work with each element of array I have to be able to extract it first. Since `array` use unique index for each element, and this index is zero(0) based I make a loop to get each element from the array. And because every array is zero based I have `for (int i = 0 ..` so later on I can get my zero element `arr[i]` which is translated as `arr[0]` when this is the first time we go through the loop. After that `i` is 1, 2, 3 so I get the next element. That's the purpose of the `for-loop` in this case.

Comment: @ps2goat This is just like a history lesson and I think it's very good that while still learning they start from the beginning. It's good to know from where you start so you know why the things get to where they are now.

Comment: I agree.  The best developers not only know how, but *why* things are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot leron for the help!

Comment: I have just one last query, would it be possible to remove only one of the high/min values if there is more than one? because i think that i what is required in the task. Thanks again

Comment: Just don't add the second code block. I added it exactly because the first block is removing only one min and one max value so if you have several min/max values like - `[1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7]` it will extract only on `1` and one `7` leaving you with `[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]` -notice that you still have two sevens, only one is removed. If that's what you want use only the first code block. If you want to extract from the sum all min/max values as if you sum  `[4,5,6]` (if we use the above array as reference) then add the second code block.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. I should have been clearer, i will clarify some more. Lets take the example of the array in your comment [1, 1, 4, 5, 7, 7, 7], the final addition should be 1+4+5+6+7. Thanks for the reply again :)

Comment: And if you have `[1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7]` then what's makes the sum - `1+4+4+5+6+6+7` or you want each number to be taken only once, not only the min and max like that - `1+4+5+6+7`?

Comment: if multiple min and max, eg [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7], then the addition will be 1+4+4+5+6+6+7