# c# find max value recursive (fastest)

Tags: c#, arrays, testing, recursion, max

I'm out of ideas on this one. Tried originally myself and then copied from SO and google, which worked on all cases except one, however still didn't find a recursive algorithm that is fast enough for that particular test case in my assignment :/

In any case, why this:

```
        public static int FindMaximum(int[] array)
        {
            if (array is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
            }

            if (array.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(null);
            }

            return FindMaxRec(array, array.Length);
        }

        public static int FindMaxRec(int[] arr, int n)
        {
            if (n == 1)
            {
                return arr[0];
            }

            return Math.Max(arr[n - 1], FindMaxRec(arr, n - 1));
        }
```

doesn't work with this `TestCase`?:

```
        [Test]
        [Order(0)]
        [Timeout(5_000)]
        public void FindMaximum_TestForLargeArray()
        {
            int expected = this.max;
            int actual = FindMaximum(this.array);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
```

**EDIT 1:**

This works fine though, but I need recursive:

```
        public static int FindMaximum(int[] array)
        {
            if (array is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
            }

            if (array.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(null);
            }

            int maxValue = int.MinValue;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] > maxValue)
                {
                    maxValue = array[i];
                }
            }

            return maxValue;
        }
```

Comment: What are "this.max" and "this.array"? That's kind of key to understanding the test case.

Comment: What are the constraints? Is sorting not allowed? Also why not try an iterative approach instead of recursive?

Comment: only LINQ is not allowed for this particular assignment. The task is to find the maximum value in a array using recursion, we can try sorting

Comment: @bschellekens this.max = 10_000_000; this.array = Enumerable.Range(1, this.max).ToArray();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find Min-Max values of array without using Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439098/find-min-max-values-of-array-without-using-linq)

Comment: One more question, when you say "it doesn't work" what does that mean? Wrong result? Exception?

Comment: @zaggler that's a negative. I know how to find max value and I think the fastest way is just using a loop (beginner hypothesis), but the idea is using recursion

Comment: @bschellekens triggers timeout, needs to be `[Timeout(5_000)]`

Comment: I'm not quite sure, why an recursive algorithm should have any benefits over an iterative algorithm in findind the maximum of an unsorted array. Each of them has to look at every single element in the array. The recursion just adds additional overhead

Comment: @derpirscher my thoughts exactly :D, have to do it somehow anyway

Comment: @Linascts Iterative will be better, just a single scan should be enough. Should run in O(N) time complexity. Recursive will add the overhead of stack frames.

Comment: Hm, you have an array of lenth 10.000.000, thus you have a recursion depth of 10.000.000. No wonder that's  slow (if it even reaches the end and doesn't thow an exception). The whole idea of recusion in such a usecase is "divide and conquer". I'd personally suggest an algorithm, which splits the array into halves and then call it recursively on each half and then take the max from that two results. Do that until both halves have a length of 1 That will bring your recursion depth from 10000000 down to 24

Comment: @derpirscher splitting array into two halves was the correct solution it seems (Dmitry's solution), I had some difficulties implementing enumerator on Nigel's solution, but it should work also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try splitting array in *two*:

```
public static int FindMaximum(int[] array) {
  if (null == array)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
  if (array.Length <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentException("Empty array is not allowed.", nameof(array));

  return FindMaxRec(array, 0, array.Length - 1);
}

private static int FindMaxRec(int[] array, int from, int to) {
  if (to < from)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(to));
  if (to <= from + 1)
    return Math.Max(array[from], array[to]);

  return Math.Max(FindMaxRec(array, from, (from + to) / 2),
                  FindMaxRec(array, (from + to) / 2 + 1, to));
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Random random = new Random(123);

int[] data = Enumerable
  .Range(0, 10_000_000)
  .Select(_ => random.Next(1_000_000_000))
  .ToArray();

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();

int max = FindMaximum(data);

sw.Stop(); 

Console.WriteLine($"max  = {max}");
Console.WriteLine($"time = {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
```

**Outcome:**

```
max  = 999999635
time = 100
```

Comment: Nice, I see your point about the recursion depth.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to turn a simple linear algorithm into a recursive one is to make use of the `enumerator` of the array.

```
    public static int FindMax(int[] values)
    {
        using var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator();
        return FindMaxRecursively(enumerator, int.MinValue);
    } 

    private static T FindMaxRecursively<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, T currentMax) where T : IComparable
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) return currentMax;
        var currentValue = enumerator.Current;
        if (currentValue.CompareTo(currentMax) > 0) currentMax = currentValue;
        return FindMaxRecursively(enumerator, currentMax);
    }
```

This passes your test case and uses recursion.

Edit: Here is a more beginner friendly version of the above, with comments to explain what it is doing:

```
    public static int FindMax(IEnumerable<int> values)
    {
        using var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator();//the using statement disposes the enumerator when we are done
        //disposing the enumerator is important because we want to reset the index back to zero for the next time someone enumerates the array
        return FindMaxRecursively(enumerator, int.MinValue);
    } 


    private static int FindMaxRecursively(IEnumerator<int> enumerator, int currentMax)
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) //move to the next item in the array. If there are no more items in the array MoveNext() returns false
            return currentMax; //if there are no more items in the array return the current maximum value
        var currentValue = enumerator.Current;//this is the value in the array at the current index
        if (currentValue > currentMax) currentMax = currentValue;//if it's larger than the current maximum update the maximum
        return FindMaxRecursively(enumerator, currentMax);//continue on to the next value, making sure to pass the current maximum
    }
```

Something that might help understand this is that the `IEnumerator` is what enables `foreach` loops. Under the hood, `foreach` loops are just repeatedly calling `MoveNext` on an item that has an `IEnumerator`. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/april/essential-net-understanding-csharp-foreach-internals-and-custom-iterators-with-yield) is some more info on that topic.

Comment: I like this approach if we are just using recursion.

Comment: I can see that this will pass, however I can't understand this yet. I want to know what I am writing. Is there like a simple way to do this? Like beginner-level syntax or smth like thaT?

Comment: @Linascts I have updated my answer to include some more beginner-friendly code, and comments that explain each step

Comment: I'm not really sure, this approach does not suffer from the same issue as OP's approach. Yes it will (after some time) find the correct maximum. But it will build up a HUGE recursion stack for big input arrays (and therefore probably throw a stack overflow exception)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int findMax(int[] a, int index) {
    if (index > 0) {
        return Math.max(a[index], findMax(a, index-1))
    } else {
        return a[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on the Test Case, I have already used this example from google before.